# Logged in only custom page

Tags: customization

I have a custom page named **custom.php** then i created a new **page** inside wordpress and selected **custom.php** in the **page attribute template**

and **custom.php** page link is accessible in my front page.

the custom page shows perfectly, but i plan to make this page a **registered** members only page.
i created a custom login page aswell, named **custom_login.php** and i want non members to be redirected here first and upon login, they will access my **custom.php**

currently im using a plugin "restrict content" but this plugin displays **404** page and does not meet what i want.. instead i want this to be the **custom_login.php** page

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect non logged in users to login page using following code if they access custom.php page link. Create custom_login.php as custom template and assign it a page, in the code below i have assigned it to a page "login page" having slug "login-page"

```
function redirect_to_login(){
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page_template('custom.php') ){
        wp_redirect( home_url() . '/login-page' );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_to_login');
```